# Keep UWP SplitView open on resize

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've just experimented with the Windows Universal Apps SplitView. I recognized that the StackPanel closes when the application window is getting resized. It seems to be the default behavior, however the StackPanel keeps open at Windows apps like Mail, Calender, or Groove Music.

Does anyone know how to force the StackPanel to keep open on window resizing?

```
<SplitView x:Name="SplitView" OpenPaneLength="240" CompactPaneLength="48" IsPaneOpen="False" PaneBackground="White" Content="{Binding}" Foreground="#FF910000" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
    <SplitView.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/technology-music-sound-audio2.jpg"/>
    </SplitView.Background>
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel x:Name="SplitViewPanePanel" Background="#FFF5F5F5">
            <RadioButton x:Name="HamburgerRadioButton" Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}" Tag="" GroupName="Hamburger" Click="HamburgerRadioButton_Click"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="BackRadioButton" Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}" Tag="" Background="#FFE6E6E6" Content="Back" GroupName="Back"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="HomeRadioButton" Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}" Tag="" Content="Home" GroupName="Navigation"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="FriendsRadioButton" Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}" Tag="" Content="Friends" GroupName="Navigation"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>
</SplitView>
```

[image]

Comment: What StackPanel? Not sure what you're talking about amigo.

Comment: @ChrisW. I've added a code snipped.

Comment: I'll have to look later to see if I can't visualize what you're talking about by "closes when the app windows is getting resized" but this isn't something that's fixed with just changing IsPaneOpen to True is it?

Comment: IsPlaneOpen just sets the beginning state however if the windows is getting resized the sidebar gets minified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the `DisplayMode` to `Inline` it will stay open. Then you can use visual states and adaptive triggers to open/close it as the window resizes.

```
<SplitView x:Name="MySplitView"
           ...
           DisplayMode="Inline">
```

Note that `Inline` means that it pushes the content instead of overlaying.